# JQuery Masonry not displaying correctly when loading external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

So I'm having trouble with Masonry not properly displaying images when I load a page with JQuery into the container div. I'm trying to prevent the page from refreshing for each section. The initial loading of the page works fine, but once I load a page into the div it breaks. Here is my code.

`$('#container').load("photos.php?directory="+str, function () {
        var container = $('#container');
        container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            container.masonry();
        });
    });`

I'm even trying to reload Masonry after the images fully load in the div(I don't mind not having to do that). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I had to load the options in JQuery instead of HTML.

`$('#container').load("photos.php?directory="+str, function () {
        var container = $('#container');
        container.masonry('reloadItems');
        $('#container').masonry({
            columnWidth: 156,
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    });`